# Whats the difference between reinstalling a component in the NIC properties and unselecting it

Tags: windows-xp

In MS Windows connection properties what's the difference between uninstalling TCP/IP (for example) and unselecting it?

[image]

Comment: If you unselect instead if uninstall it you don't have to reinstall to use it again ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had wondered that - does it disable it or do nothing.

And it's not just in XP by the way, it's in Windows 7 as well.

I just tested it on XP. But I'll test for Win 7 too.

The conclusion is, it disables it.  (obviously you can then reenable it by ticking it and clicking ok)

The test was, I VNCed to the XP computer, unchecked IP, then clicked OK, and it said it'd also disable file sharing and ms client.. So, clearly it disables IP and other things dependent on it.   I clicked OK and lost my VNC connection so it worked. I went to the computer and reenabled it clicked OK and could VNC again. So that proves it.

And looking at my Windows 7 computer, for one of my network adaptors, I happen to have IPv4 ticked and IPv6 unticked. And that does disable IPv6. I tried enabling it, running ipconfig, disabling it, running ipconfig. And I can see from whether ipconfig shows an IPv6 address for that adaptor, that ticking IPv6 there, will enable or disable IPv6 for that network adaptor. So, same principle whether XP or 7. It enables/disables it.

And in retrospect, the classic way to enable/disable windows file sharing, is to tick/untick the box, and you see whether it listens on the file sharing port(s) or not, that it worked.

And as DavidPostil commented, if you uninstalled it you'd have to reinstall it.

As to when you might want to uninstall it rather than just disable it.  The following hasn't ever been of use to me but i've heard that sometimes if the TCP/IP stack can become corrupt then you would uninstall and reinstall. I used to hear about with malware, it could still happen I suppose. BTW- Just did a quick test and, interestingly, Win7 doesn't give me a UAC prompt when I uncheck file sharing.